# How to solve z^6 = -15625?

Tags: complex-numbers

$z^6 = -15625$ has six solutions.

$z^6 + 15625 = (z^2+25)(z^4-25z^2+625)$

$z^2+25 = 0$

$\Rightarrow x_{1} = -5i$

$\Rightarrow x_{2} = 5i$

That's easy, but I just don't find a way to get the other 4 solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Substitute $y = z^2$ in the second equation and solve for $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better method : try to solve $z^6 = 1$ and think about $e^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 0):

Thomas' method is better in principal, but if you insist on using factorization:
$$z^6+15625 = (z^2+25)(z^4-25z^2+625)$$
The second term is a quadratic in terms of $z^2$.  We can use the quadratic formula to find the zeros generated by the second term:
$$z^2 = \frac{-(-25) \pm \sqrt{625-4(625)}}{2}$$
(etc)